# Apple Maps conversion from Google

Tags: ios, google-maps

We built an app 6 months ago for a client that generates a map then places pins at certain locations. The pins represent past project locations of the clients... This was all done using Mapkit with Google maps... I'm assuming that is where the problem is?

Now when the application is opened the screen is black and after about 20 seconds the app will crash... It's not generating any error codes when we build the app in xcode to a device so I'm not sure what to do to fix it?

I can build directly to the device and the apple maps do load slowly.. but then when I disconnect xcode and try to open the app it never appears and crashes 
I know there have been many problems reported with apple mapping... I assume that is what is generating this issue... The question is can I still use Google maps? Or is there something I'm missing with Apple maps?

here is what is being generated in the console

> Oct  8 12:15:21 iPad locationd[40] : notify name "com.apple.locationd.DumpDiagnostics" has been registered 20 times - this may be a leak
>   Oct  8 12:15:25 iPad locationd[40] : Location icon should now be in state 'Active'
>   Oct  8 12:15:25 iPad kernel[0] : launchd[2833] Builtin profile: container (sandbox)
>   Oct  8 12:15:25 iPad kernel[0] : launchd[2833] Container: /private/var/mobile/Applications/AB86A47D-1D6A-4CD4-8E8F-4BE09907A0C3 (sandbox)
>   Oct  8 12:15:26 iPad locationd[40] : NETWORK: requery, 0, 0, 33, 0, items, fQueryRetries, 0, fLastRetryTimestamp, 371405504.4
>   Oct  8 12:15:26 iPad locationd[40] : NETWORK: query, cells, 0, 0, 33, wifis, 0
>   Oct  8 12:15:44 iPad backboardd[51] : com.Virtusventures.Mapin failed to launch in time
>   Oct  8 12:15:44 iPad backboardd[51] : Forcing crash report of Mapin[2833]...
>   Oct  8 12:15:45 iPad backboardd[51] : Finished crash reporting.
>   Oct  8 12:15:45 iPad com.apple.launchd[1] (UIKitApplication:com.Virtusventures.Mapin[0x696][2833]) : (UIKitApplication:com.Virtusventures.Mapin[0x696]) Exited: Killed: 9
>   Oct  8 12:15:45 iPad backboardd[51] : Application 'UIKitApplication:com.Virtusventures.Mapin[0x696]' exited abnormally with signal 9: Killed: 9        Oct  8 12:15:45 iPad ReportCrash[2834] : libMobileGestalt copySystemVersionDictionaryValue: Could not lookup ReleaseType from system version dictionary
>   Oct  8 12:15:45 iPad ReportCrash[2834] : Saved crashreport to /var/mobile/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/Mapin_2012-10-08-121544_iPad.plist using uid: 0 gid: 0, synthetic_euid: 501 egid: 0
>   Oct  8 12:15:55 iPad locationd[40] : Location icon should now be in state 'Inactive'

This is what is displaying when I am not building to the device and simply trying to open the app

> Oct  8 12:38:48 ipad geod[1066] : /SourceCache/GeoServices/GeoServices-457.9/GEOResourceManifestServerLocalProxy.m:1072 connection error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out." UserInfo=0x1ed36780 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://gspa21.ls.apple.com/config/prod-resources-lodpi-18, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://gspa21.ls.apple.com/config/prod-resources-lodpi-18, NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out., NSUnderlyingError=0x1ed3d450 "The request timed out."}

Answer (score 0):

Your app is not launching in  time and is being killed by the watchdog timer.

From your logs:

> Mapin failed to launch in time Oct 8 12:15:44 iPad backboardd[51] :
>   Forcing crash report of Mapin[2833]...

You probably need to move lengthy startup tasks to a background thread.

Comment: Yep the question is why?  It worked for months using google maps, We used MapKit before so now the only difference should be the maps being displayed.

Comment: Perhaps Apple's mapping / location services infrastructure is less robust than Google's, leading to longer load times?

Comment: I also just built it to a device running ios 5 and it works fine (again using google maps)

Comment: I was wondering the same... When I build directly to the device it does take some time to open but the app will function... so the connection to xcode stops it from timing out... but if you disconnect it will crash...

Comment: That makes sense. Launching apps on devices using Xcode disables some of the watchdog timers.

Comment: So the question is there a fix for this or a way to go back to google maps?... it seams that it is working the way it should but because of apple maps we have the problem...

Comment: since the app does connect and work eventually when connected to xcode is there a way to overwrite the time out feature?.. I would say it takes about a minute to a minute and a half for it to finally connect.

Comment: I don't think so, the persistent watchdog timer is an OS-level monitor.

Comment: Ok so we have been playing with the code and taking out almost all of the pins and only loading the maps first.  We added a button in to display the pins but the app still crashes on start up.  So the only thing it's doing right now on start up is loading the map

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17723/discussion-between-marco-and-monergy)